# Let $x_1 = 3, x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{4-x_n}, \text{for } n \geq 1$. Use induction to show that $0 < x_{n+1} < x_n < 4, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction, recurrence-relations

Let

$$x_1 = 3, x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{4-x_n}, \text{for } n \geq 1$$

Use induction to show that $0 < x_{n+1} < x_n < 4, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

Let $S(n)$ be the proposition that $0 < x_{n+1} < x_n < 4$.

Base Case:

$S(1)$, and thus $x_1 = 3$, $x_2 = \frac{1}{4-3} = 1$. We have $ 0 < 1 < 3 < 4$, thus $S(1)$ holds.

---

Inductive Hypothesis (strong):

Assume that $S(n)$ holds for $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Assume $S(i)$ holds therefore. So,  $0 < x_{i+1} < x_i < 4$

---

Inductive Step:

Show that $S(i + 1)$ holds.

This is where I am stuck on the IS. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need to prove by induction is the stronger statement that $x_n$ is decreasing and:
$$S(n):2-\sqrt 3<x_{n+1}<x_n\le3$$

$S(1)$ is obviously true. Then if $S(n-1)$ is true ($2-\sqrt 3<x_n<x_{n-1}\le3$) then:

$$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4-x_n}>\frac{1}{4-(2-\sqrt 3)}=2-\sqrt 3$$

$$x_n-x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{1}{4-x_n}=\frac{-x_n^2+4x_n-1}{4-x_n}=\frac{3-(x_n-2)^2}{4-x_n}>0$$

since ${4-x_n}>0$ (obviously), and $3-(x_n-2)^2>0$ is equivalent to $2-\sqrt 3<x_n<2+\sqrt 3$, which is also true by the hypothesis of induction.

So you proved that $2-\sqrt 3<x_{n+1}<x_n\le3$ , which is exactly $S(n)$. Done.

Comment: Why are you subtracting $x_n - x_{n+1}$

Comment: To prove that $x_n-x_{n+1}>0$, which is the same with $x_{n+1}<x_n$

Comment: @Momo $2−sqrt{3} < x_{n+1} < x_n ≤ 3$ does not by itself imply $S_n$. The upper bound is OK, but the lower bound does not. But of course, fixing the lower-bound issue is easy.

Comment: @PDE Are you commenting on my proof or on yours?

Answer (score 0):

If $x_n < 4$, then $x_{n+1} = \dfrac{1}{4-x_n} < x_n$ holds iff $1 < x_n(4-x_n)$, i.e. $x_n^2-4x_n+1 < 0$.

This is equivalant to $(x_n-2)^2 < 3$, which holds for $2-\sqrt{3} < x_n < 2+\sqrt{3} \approx 3.73$.

So $0 < x_n < 4$ isn't a strong enough assumption to prove the inductive hypothesis.

Instead, try to show that $2-\sqrt{3} < x_{n+1} < x_n < 2+\sqrt{3}$ for all $n$ (which is a stronger statement).

Comment: I think the problem is actually with the lower bound, because $x_1 = 3 \lt 2+\sqrt 3$. The statement should be stronger in the other direction as well $2-\sqrt 3 \lt x_{n+1} \lt x_n \lt 2 + \sqrt 3$

Comment: @benji Yes, it is the lower bound which is the most important, the upper is not that much important (I did exactly that in my solution).

Comment: Yes, it is just as easy to show that "$2-\sqrt{3} < x_{n+1} < x_n < 2+\sqrt{3}$ for all $n$" using induction. However, proving "$0 < x_{n+1} < x_n < 2+\sqrt{3}$ for all $n$" is sufficient for the given question.

Comment: If you allow $x_n<2-\sqrt 3$, then you can no longer guarantee $x_{n+1}<x_n$

Comment: ^Ahh yes, my bad. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Having proven the base case $S_1$, assume that, indeed,

$$
x_{i+1} = \frac{1}{4-x_i}.
$$

By induction,

$$
x_{i+2} = \frac{1}{4-x_{i+1}} = \frac{1}{4-\frac{1}{4-x_i}}=\frac{4-x_i}{15-4x_i}.
$$

Find the values of $x_i$ for which $S_{i+1}$ is true. Yet for $S_{i+1}$ to be true, it is necessary (but insufficient) to show that $x_{i+2} < x_{i+1}$ is likewise true. Therefore, the problem reduces to showing that for all natural numbers $i > 1$,

$$
\frac{4-x_i}{15-4x_i} < \frac{1}{4-x_i}
$$

That is,
$$ 
\begin{align}
15 - 4x_i & > 16 - 8x_i + x_{i}^2 \\
0 & > x_{i}^2-4x_n+1 \\
& > (x_{i}^2-4x_n+4)-3 \\
0 & > (x_i-2)^2 - 3 \\
3 & > (x_i-2)^2 \\
-\sqrt{3} &< x_i-2 < \sqrt{3} \\
0 &< 2-\sqrt{3} < x_i < 2+\sqrt{3} \\.
\end{align}
$$

This last result is exactly $S_i$. More specifically, the last block of equations proves that $S_i$ iff $S_{i+1}$. *Q.E.D.* $\blacksquare$

Comment: There is a $4-x_i$ which got lost in translation when you calculated $x_{i+2}$

Comment: @Momo Where? Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: $x_{i+2}\ne\frac{1}{15-4x_i}$ :(

Comment: @Momo I've fixed it.

Comment: ...but $2-\sqrt 3<x_i$ does not follow from the hypothesis of induction, so at the very least needs to be proved separately.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would post an answer without changing the induction (though there's nothing wrong with doing that!)
We assume:
$$0 \lt x_{i+1} \lt x_i \ldots \lt x_1=3 < 4$$
We need to show:
$$ 0 \lt x_{i+2} \lt x_{i+1} \lt 4$$
First, $x_{i+1} \lt \ldots x_1 \lt 4$
If we can show that $x_{i+2} \lt x_{i+1}$ then $x_{i+2} \lt 4$ and then $x_{i+2} = 1/(4-x_{i+1}) \gt 0$

So let's show that $x_{i+2} \lt x_{i+1}$

$$
x_{i+2} = \frac{1}{4-x_{i+1}} \lt x_{i+1} \iff 2 - \sqrt 3 \lt x_{i+1} \lt 2+\sqrt 3
$$

We know that $x_{i+1} < x_1 = 3 < 2+\sqrt 3$

Let's assume that $x_{i+1} \le 2-\sqrt 3$ then
$$x_{i+1} = \frac{1}{4-x_i} \le 2- \sqrt 3$$
Simplifying this gives $x_i \le 2 - \sqrt 3$ but then $x_{i-1} \le 2 - \sqrt 3$ this leads to $x_1 \le 2 - \sqrt 3$ which is a contradiction!

Comment: In other words you've proved $2-\sqrt 3<x_i<2+\sqrt 3$ in a separate induction, just to avoid adding it to the original induction :)